# in/over the 25-year period

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that overall consumption of beef and lamb decreased. I mean I want describe the overall trends. In this case, should I use "in" or "over"?

> People consumed much less beef and lamb **in/over** the 25-year period.

[image]

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but in IELTS, I only saw 'over' being used in this sense. Please note that 'over' here means 'during [the priod of 25 years],' whereas 'in' means 'after/in the end [of the period of 25 yeras].'

Comment: I first used "over". I hired a native speaker to correct my writing. He change it to "in". Hopefully, native speakers here can tell us which preposition is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically, there is nothing wrong with either, although they would mean different things:

> People consumed much less beef and lamb over the 25-year period.

This could mean that the **total** amount consumed during this period is less than in another period. You'd have to state what that period was.

> People consumed much less beef and lamb in the 25-year period.

This could mean that, at specific points, their consumption was lower than at any point in whatever other period you are comparing to. Again, you'd have to state the other period for comparison.

However, **this graph alone shows neither of those things**. The graph shows no period other than the 25 years mentioned to compare to, so the comparative form of 'less' would be incorrect, unless there is some other period in the wider context you have not shared with us.

What this graph shows in isolation is that consumption *reduced*, or *fell* during the 25-year period, because the figures at the end of the period are lower than at the start and, while there are some peaks and troughs in the data points, the overall trend for both types of meat is downward.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you tell me if it's correct to use the singular "consumption" with "both"? The **consumption** of beef and lamb **both** fell significantly during the 25-year period.

Comment: I'd say "The consumption of both beef and lamb fell significantly during the 25-year period."